# Can't execute python script from php

Tags: php, python

**Solved**

Before writing a new question i search for a solution all over the web.
I have a raspberry pi with apache2, php5.4,ssl.
I want to execute a python script from php one.
The php script is inside /var/www, which has 777 permission.
Php file:

```
shell_exec('python /home/pi/Desktop/Python/prova.py');
```

Prova.py has 750 permission but his group owner is www-data, which is the user printed by shell_exec('whoami'); which works.
Prova.py:

```
print "Hello World"
```

The script works directly from the command line:

```
php filename.php
```

It does not work from broswer!

*Finally i succeed in execute the script from the browser.
I had to add www-data user to sudoers file with its related permission:*

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /etc/bin/python
```

Comment: `Prova.py` != `prova.py`, check what's really the name of your python script. Do you get an error message (check your server logs)? Also, `www-data` needs to have the permission to access `/home/pi/Desktop/Python/`

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is this:
When launching the php script through the console, you are launching php with the permissions of your current user.
When a process is executed through opening it in the browser, it will have the permissions of the user of your web-server-process.

Your group permissions will have to be 7 no matter what. Either change the python scripts permissions to `777` (read-write-execute for everybody) or change it to `770` and make sure that your web-servers user is inside the group set to the file.

Comment: I tried to move prova.py in a subdirectory of var/www and now...fortunately it works!

Comment: I tried to complicate python script in order to play a sound. So I imported time and pygame libraries, the problem has returned. It works from command line but no via browser

Comment: What permissions are currently set on the file?

Answer (score -2):

I had an issue similar while trying to build a web interface to change the image on an inky pHAT. Turns out www-data doesn't have access to GPIO.OUT. Tested by running "sudo -u www-data php index.php" and it returned the error I was looking for. So I give www-data GPIO permission "usermod -a -G gpio www-data" instead of adding to suddoers.