# Execute python in a php script using shell_exec()

Tags: php, python

I'm experiencing a weird problem in trying to execute python in a php server (LAMP). (safe_mode off)

if I type:

```
$output = shell_exec("ls -lah");
echo "<pre>$Output</pre>";
```

I got the result of the `ls` command. Same for`$output = shell_exec("tar --version");` and other applications, such as gzip.

However, if I switch for any of these lines:

```
$output = shell_exec("python --version");
$output = shell_exec("python2.7 --version");
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python --version");
$output = shell_exec("python my_script.py");
```

And other variants of this kind, I get no results. The command is not being executed, the python bitecode not made and the `echo` remains silent.

I have also tried with the `exec()` command with no more success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP and shell\_exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214031/php-and-shell-exec)

Comment: Maybe a right problem ?

Comment: I've read this post in detail as many other, i didn't find any answer there

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689684/cant-execute-python-script-from-php This could be a answer for this.

Answer (score 11):

I think this may help...

looks like the output for the python call needs to be routed properly. 
I was able to make this work within my index.php file for returning the python version...

```
shell_exec("python -V 2>&1");
```

[Here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10267623-Can-t-get-shell_exec%28%29-to-return-python-V-result) is where I found the answer.

Comment: I also had the same error with `pdftk`. But it explains why. "/opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by pdftk)". This may be the case with python? Let me experiment a bit..

Comment: Worked for me too, but specifically for me, running in shared hosting managed with CPanel. My py scripts are below the /public_html root, and using $out = shell_exec('python ../pyscr/script.py '.param1.' 2>&1');  puts the print values from script.py into $out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run the python script using the following code

```
$output = shell_exec("python my_script.py");
```

you will need to use absolute path for my_script.py and give all permissions (I am not sure which ones are sufficient) for the python file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refer to the full path for your python.

for example use this instead:

```
$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/python full_path/my_script.py")
```

instead of:

```
$output = shell_exec("python my_script.py");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think kernel not able to find the path for python where it is installed..if you can do echo $PATH..it will show all the paths where to be search a command if given
add your python part there and then it may work or you can give absolute path(other than /usr/bin/) see if it works..I need to test it too.

Comment: it is also possible that ls and gzip are working because these are system commands..what you are using is exclusive or other command..will let you know once I test it on my hp ux box

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your fast reply!
I have tried echo $PATH                                                                                              
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/share/java/apache-ant/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

The python interpreter is located in the /usr/bin/ so it should find it, no?

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
which python
```

tell you, both from the command line and from shell_exec()? It should tell you which (if any) Python interpreter it's finding (from `$PATH`). Don't forget that it's quite possible that the `$PATH` used from the Linux command line might not be the same as the `$PATH` used by shell_exec()! Once you find the Python interpreter you want to use, you *might* have to hard code it in the shell_exec().

Comment: Hi Phil! `which python` gives exactely the same answer from both the command line and php: `/usr/bin/python`. The problem may not come from this...

Comment: BTW, `shell_exec('echo $PATH');` gives the same answer in the console and the terminal: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the web server doesn't have appropriate rights to execute shell commands. To fix this, run the 'sudo visudo' command and add the following line to the sudoers file:

www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL

Also, make sure that the /var/www directory belongs to the www-data user and group (use sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www to set the correct owner). The details are here http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2014/07/PHP-on-Raspberry-Pi

Also refer
[Can't execute python script from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689684/cant-execute-python-script-from-php)